# CNContactViewController - "UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. "

Tags: swift, cncontactviewcontroller

iOS 17 (Xcode 15)

When I display the a contact using the UI framework, I get this in the console:

> UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.

```
      let contact = CNContact()
      let cnVC = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: contact)
      present(cnVC, animated: true)
```

How do I do "Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents", when I don't have custom code for this? I think the color problem is inside the `ContactsUI` framework.

UPDATE:
I set the symbolic breakpoint, and ran it again and I see:

```
UIKitCore`UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents:
->  0x103885104 <+0>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x40
    0x103885108 <+4>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x10388510c <+8>:   add    x29, sp, #0x30
    0x103885110 <+12>:  adrp   x8, 4606
    0x103885114 <+16>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #0xaf8]
    0x103885118 <+20>:  str    x8, [sp, #0x8]
    0x10388511c <+24>:  adrp   x8, 2957
    0x103885120 <+28>:  ldr    d0, [x8, #0x2d8]
    0x103885124 <+32>:  str    d0, [sp, #0x10]
    0x103885128 <+36>:  adrp   x8, 0
    0x10388512c <+40>:  add    x8, x8, #0x178            ; __UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents_block_invoke
    0x103885130 <+44>:  adrp   x9, 4619
    0x103885134 <+48>:  add    x9, x9, #0x5f0            ; __block_descriptor_40_e5_v8?0l
    0x103885138 <+52>:  stp    x8, x9, [sp, #0x18]
    0x10388513c <+56>:  adrp   x8, 3061
    0x103885140 <+60>:  add    x8, x8, #0x1ef            ; "UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents"
    0x103885144 <+64>:  str    x8, [sp, #0x28]
    0x103885148 <+68>:  adrp   x8, 5726
    0x10388514c <+72>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #0xc00]
    0x103885150 <+76>:  cmn    x8, #0x1
    0x103885154 <+80>:  b.ne   0x103885164               ; <+96>
    0x103885158 <+84>:  ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x10388515c <+88>:  add    sp, sp, #0x40
    0x103885160 <+92>:  ret    
    0x103885164 <+96>:  adrp   x0, 5726
    0x103885168 <+100>: add    x0, x0, #0xc00            ; UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents.once
    0x10388516c <+104>: add    x1, sp, #0x8
    0x103885170 <+108>: bl     0x1042cc8f4               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
    0x103885174 <+112>: b      0x103885158               ; <+84>
```

Comment: Look up how to set a "Symbolic Breakpoint". Set the symbol to `UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents`.

Comment: Added more info. I'm not familiar with this area, so I don't have any analysis I can contribute.

Comment: looking around iOS17, there were changes to the presented sheet, the problem is probably in the new look.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too, have filed a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I don't know a lot about debugging in this area, so if there's a next step in analyzing the data, pls. advise. (The related questions on this topic showed sample code where people pass in invalid values, is that visible in the additional info from the symbolic breakpoint?